# How to execute a query automatically in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there any ways to execute a SQL query automatically after 30 days? Actually I want to change the status of an account from active to inactive in database without manual editing

Comment: Set up a cron job like described in this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190561/what-is-the-best-method-for-scheduled-tasks-in-php

Comment: use cronjobs for this

Comment: cron jobs, database triggers, all sorts of options. Check out some of the links posted.

Comment: you need to create a batch which might run in daily basis, which will call that particular script.

Answer (score 2):

You need do it with cronjob, edit your **/etc/crontab** file to setup a new job like:

```
0 0 30 * * apache php /path/yourScript.php
```

This will be executed each day 30 of month.

Comment: +1 and just an FYI to OP, you'd need to make sure you have CLI PHP installed.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 5.1.6+ has an [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html).

If you're using an earlier version, you could write a little script which executed the desired SQL, and schedule it with at, cron or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use Event Scheduler in mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
  CREATE EVENT e_hourly
        ON SCHEDULE
          EVERY 1 HOUR DO ***your update query here***
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup a cronjob on the server, like Ignacio Ocampo said.

In your database, you have to create a column (last_activity) to track the last time the user has logged in (I recommend using unix timestamp)

Then, on the PHP script that will run the cronjob, you update the rows, for example:

PHP: `$timestamp = time() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;`

SQL: `UPDATE users_table SET active = 0 WHERE last_activity < $timestamp`